# How to get a JSON string from URL?

Tags: c#, json, facebook, linq-to-xml, webclient

I'm switching my code form XML to JSON.

But I can't find how to get a JSON string from a given URL.

The URL is something like this: "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=.....&format=json"

I used XDocuments before, there I could use the load method:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.load("URL");
```

What is the equivalent of this method for JSON? I'm using JSON.NET.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Use the `WebClient` class in `System.Net`:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
```

Keep in mind that `WebClient` is `IDisposable`, so you would probably add a `using` statement to this in production code.  This would look like:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   var json = wc.DownloadString("url");
}
```

Comment: Why do you skip the using statement that is used in the answer from Jon?

Comment: It didn't work for me until I put `var json = wc.DownloadString("url");` in `try-catch` block!

Comment: I found error "HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address".. this is URL : "http://localhost:5200/testapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json, but it's worked with  URL : https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

Comment: WebClient is now obsolete and you should use httpClient.GetStringAsync as shown below by Richard Garside.

Answer (score 109):

AFAIK JSON.Net does not provide functionality for reading from a URL. So you need to do this in two steps:

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
    // Now parse with JSON.Net
}
```

Comment: @jsmith: It wasn't a suggestion... the OP mentioned it :)

Comment: Thx for helping me out, It's strange that i didn't find this on google, this realy was a basic question isn't it? I'm now having an error like: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'. I know that it is some attribute in my class that is not right declared, but i just can't find wich one. But i'm still trying! :)

Answer (score 56):

If you're using .NET 4.5 and want to use async then you can use `HttpClient` in `System.Net.Http`:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("url");

    // Now parse with JSON.Net
}
```

Comment: You have to use it in a `Task` with `async`