# Create a new content type to consume JSON

Tags: orchardcms, content-type

I need to create a new content type in orchard cms that will only have a field indicating a json url to be consumed.
My question is how to consume json in content-type and return the data consumed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue a web request using eg. [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) (or built-in [WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url)) and return deserialized data. RestSharp already has a JSON deserializer built-in, but if you need more robust solution you can use [JSON.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/json).

The request would be best done in one of the content part handler events (eg. `OnLoaded`) - just set a value of some property on your custom part to the returned data from there.

Comment: ok, thank you. I just need to know how to do that in orchard cms

Comment: what do you think about create a new module to do this?