# Fetch JSON data from web

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm making a C# metro application that utilizes JSON. The following code works fine when the JSON file is stored locally, but when I put it on a server, it doesn't work:

```
Uri dataUri = new Uri("http://localhost/results.json");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();
```

Comment: Does your sever have a localhost? (AKA is http://localhost/results.json anything?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url I think you should use webclient as shown in this example.

Comment: @burdock Yes I'm running WAMP Server and have the JSON file stored in the www folder

Comment: I can't - that's for plain C# and I can't use Webclient in a Metro application

Comment: Check if its a path(ing) issue : try  `new Uri(location.origin + "/results.json")`