# Trying to receive JSON with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, weather, c3

I've started building an app to get tide info, weather info, mapping capabilities, etc from World Weather Online, but it can't get the JSON response.

I've installed JSON.net via NuGet, am running Windows 8.1. I've only been able to even view the data by pasting my JSON URL into an actual browser. Then using its output at json2sharp to create the bottom part of my code below.

Tried http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i and [How to get a json string from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities;





namespace EOD_Assistant
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void myMap_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myMap.MapProvider = BingHybridMapProvider.Instance;
            myMap.SetPositionByKeywords("Comox, Canada");
            myMap.MinZoom = 1;
            myMap.MaxZoom = 17;
            myMap.Zoom = 10;
            myMap.CanDragMap = true;
            myMap.MapScaleInfoEnabled = true;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url =  "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Campbell%20River&format=json&num_of_days=5&callback=rrr&key=1ccf49ff57a386e570286ae9294b9";

        }

        private void GetWeather()
        {
        }

        private void weatherBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class WeatherDesc
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class WeatherIconUrl
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class CurrentCondition
        {
            public string cloudcover { get; set; }
            public string FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
            public string FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
            public string humidity { get; set; }
            public string observation_time { get; set; }
            public string precipMM { get; set; }
            public string pressure { get; set; }
            public string temp_C { get; set; }
            public string temp_F { get; set; }
            public string visibility { get; set; }
            public string weatherCode { get; set; }
            public List<WeatherDesc> weatherDesc { get; set; }
            public List<WeatherIconUrl> weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
            public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
            public string winddirDegree { get; set; }
            public string windspeedKmph { get; set; }
            public string windspeedMiles { get; set; }
        }

        public class Request
        {
            public string query { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Astronomy
        {
            public string moonrise { get; set; }
            public string moonset { get; set; }
            public string sunrise { get; set; }
            public string sunset { get; set; }
        }

        public class WeatherDesc2
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class WeatherIconUrl2
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Hourly
        {
            public string chanceoffog { get; set; }
            public string chanceoffrost { get; set; }
            public string chanceofhightemp { get; set; }
            public string chanceofovercast { get; set; }
            public string chanceofrain { get; set; }
            public string chanceofremdry { get; set; }
            public string chanceofsnow { get; set; }
            public string chanceofsunshine { get; set; }
            public string chanceofthunder { get; set; }
            public string chanceofwindy { get; set; }
            public string cloudcover { get; set; }
            public string DewPointC { get; set; }
            public string DewPointF { get; set; }
            public string FeelsLikeC { get; set; }
            public string FeelsLikeF { get; set; }
            public string HeatIndexC { get; set; }
            public string HeatIndexF { get; set; }
            public string humidity { get; set; }
            public string precipMM { get; set; }
            public string pressure { get; set; }
            public string tempC { get; set; }
            public string tempF { get; set; }
            public string time { get; set; }
            public string visibility { get; set; }
            public string weatherCode { get; set; }
            public List<WeatherDesc2> weatherDesc { get; set; }
            public List<WeatherIconUrl2> weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
            public string WindChillC { get; set; }
            public string WindChillF { get; set; }
            public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
            public string winddirDegree { get; set; }
            public string WindGustKmph { get; set; }
            public string WindGustMiles { get; set; }
            public string windspeedKmph { get; set; }
            public string windspeedMiles { get; set; }
        }

        public class Weather
        {
            public List<Astronomy> astronomy { get; set; }
            public string date { get; set; }
            public List<Hourly> hourly { get; set; }
            public string maxtempC { get; set; }
            public string maxtempF { get; set; }
            public string mintempC { get; set; }
            public string mintempF { get; set; }
            public string uvIndex { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public List<CurrentCondition> current_condition { get; set; }
            public List<Request> request { get; set; }
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Data data { get; set; }
        }

        public class PleaseWORK
        {
            private static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new()
            {
                using (var w = new WebClient())
                {
                    var json_data = string.Empty;
                    // attempt to download JSON data as a string
                    try
                    {
                        json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                    // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
                    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure wether you're using the premium or free version but in either case you absolutely should not share your api key . . . (and if it's premium people could use it and you'd end up paying)

Comment: You should probably clarify just what's going wrong. What exception is thrown, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol is missing in the url

```
string url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Campbell%20River&format=json&num_of_days=5&callback=rrr&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(url); //THIS GIVES ME AN EXCEPTION ERROR....DUNNO WHY.

}
```

and the JSON string returnd by the api is not correct, it starts with "rrr" (at the time of writing of course)

Comment: Thank you so much. No more errors except I can't populate the information now. Or rather I can't use it. When I put in the code to use it I get an error. I'm trying to call it like so when I push the weather button var rootObject = _download_serialized_json_data<RootObject>(url);  But it won't take.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Campbell%20River&format=json&num_of_days=5&callback=rrr&key=1ccf49ff57a386e570286ae9294b9";
               var jsonString = web.DownloadString(url).ToString();
               var parseJsonString = jsonString.Split('(', ')')[1];
               var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(parseJsonString);
```

This works, Check it...

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSON string in this way

```
   // httpWebRequest with API URL
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
        ("http://YourURL.com");

        //Method GET
        request.Method = "GET";

        //HttpWebResponse for result
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        //Mapping of status code
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == "")
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

            //Get news data in json string
            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

After that you can convert that string to DataSet also like this.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(data);
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're using is not correct.

To get valid json, you should use :

```
http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Campbell%20River&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The only difference is that i took out the `&callback=rrr`