# WebClient.DownloadString doesn't return value

Tags: c#, json

I have one URL with some special characters like `|` and `&`. 
URL is returning JSON data.

When I am trying this URL in browser it will run and return json data but when I am trying using `WebClient.DownloadString()`, it will not work.

Example :

**Using Browser :**

```
http://websvr.test.com/abc.aspx?Action=B&PacketList=116307638|1355.00

Output : 
[{"Column1":106,"Column2":"Buying Successfully."}]
```

**Using WebClient.DownloadString():**

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
       var json = wc.DownloadString("http://websvr.test.com/abc.aspx?Action=B&PacketList=116307638|1355.00");

    }

Output : 
[{"Column1":-107,"Column2":"Invalid Parametrer Required-(RefNo|JBPrice)!"}]
```

Comment: show code please, else no one can help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url How to get a json string from url?

Comment: I think I've a similar problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715042/c-sharp-webclient-get-html-as-string-with-parameters-in-url. Did you found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set webclient's encoding before call `DownloadString()` and encode url using [UrlEncode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
WebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var url = WebUtility.UrlEncode("http://websvr.test.com/abc.aspx?Action=B&PacketList=116307638|1355.00");
var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: I am also trying WebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; but not working.

Comment: @NikhilSangani Blanl value? But in the question you wrote that you got: `[{"Column1":-107,"Column2":"Invalid Parametrer Required-(RefNo|JBPrice)!"}]`. So, what did you get in response?

Comment: sorry MegaTron, I got [{"Column1":-107,"Column2":"Invalid Parametrer Required-(RefNo|JBPrice)!"}], but when i put url in browser it works fine. i think problem is  " | " character.

Answer (score 1):

You should encode `PacketList` parameter in your URL, because it includes pipe character, which must be encoded to `%7c`. Browsers automatically encode necessary characters in URL, but you should encode it in code manually.

```
    var json = wc.DownloadString("http://websvr.test.com/abc.aspx?Action=B&PacketList=" + 
                  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("116307638|1355.00");
```