# C# WebClient get HTML as string with parameters in URL

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I'm trying to get the HTML source as string from the following website:

[https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/CCValue?mal|ShowSecond=Browse&First=malc2](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/CCValue?mal%7CShowSecond=Browse&First=malc2)

But when I'm using `WebClient` in C#:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string s = client.DownloadString("https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/CCValue?mal|ShowSecond=Browse&First=malc2");
```

I'm getting back `you have supplied an ill-formed request` from the website and not the correlation coefficient I'm looking for.

I took as well a look at the following question [How to post data to specific URL using WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp) but it didn't helped me.

I think the problem has to do with the `|` character in the URL. If you click on the link above it doesn't work because the `|` is replaced by `%7C`.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)` opens the correct page in a browser.

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAYWEu

**Update**

Using Wireshark and switching to http I can see that the `|` character gets replaced by `%7C`.

```
144 2.241432    10.131.36.167   195.176.26.193  HTTP    253 GET http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/CCValue?mal%7CShowSecond=Browse&First=malc2 HTTP/1.1
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: what options you selected in the form that gives that url?

Comment: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Correlations/index.html then `alpha particle mass energy equivalent` and `alpha particle mass`.

Comment: There's a difference between the `UploadString` referred to in the question you linked to and the `DownloadString` method you're calling in your code.

Comment: @phuzi I tried it as well with `UploadString` and separating the URL and parameters. No success.

Comment: @Wollmich You should use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) nowdays instead of WebClient. Even Microsoft recommends [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks). Anyway, I think you are out of luck, it seems it is the service that is not doing a proper job handling the querystring-parameters. The request https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/CCValue?mal%7CShowSecond=Browse&First=malc2 should work if they did a proper decoding on their end.