# XMLHttpRequest with Microsoft Script Control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to stack overflow and fairly new to programming so bear with me.
I apologize in advance for any typos.

Planning to use `C#` console application to extract data from a Web API.
Did not find alot of information on how to execute a javascript function from the .cs file. So i decided to try out Microsoft Script Control.
I am trying to send a `xmlhttpRequest` using Microsoft Script Control. But I keep getting

> "XMLHttpRequest is undefined".

```
        ScriptControl js = new ScriptControl();
        js.AllowUI = false;
        js.Language = "JScript";
        js.Reset();
        js.AddCode(@"
   function test()
    {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'WEB API LINK', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', processRequest, false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

   function processRequest(e) 
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                return response;
            }
        }
     }
  }
");
```

Not sure if this even works with Script Control. When using the script in a regular html page inside `<script> </script>` it works except that I havent been able to send data or retrieve data from .html to .cs. Any different routes would be appreciated.

Regards
RiceNor

Comment: Wait what no please don't! - download [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url) then parse json [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Thank you, il check out those.

Comment: Any possibility to flag this as answered when it is only a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this answered i paste Alex K. comment
Download like this [How to get a json string from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url)

then parse json like this [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)