# How can I convert webpage unicode to ascii?

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient, non-ascii-characters

I am attempting to convert a webpage from a format I don't understand to ascii so I can look for certain data.  I retrieve the data using webclient with a url of the web page and then using encoding to convert the data from what I think is unicode to ascii but the format doesn't change at all.  Below is my code:

```cs
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string page = "https://www.myurl.com/";

Stream data = web.OpenRead(page);
StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(data);
string input = reader1.ReadToEnd();
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;

string webpage = ascii.GetString(
  Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicode.GetBytes(input))
);
```

Below is what the webpage data looks like which is the same as the input data which suggests my conversion didn't work.

```
     \"sprited\":true,\"spriteCssClass\":\"sx_a11c08\",\"spriteMapCssClass\":\"sp_SN-oNOqlzVS\"},\"505789\":{\"sprited\":true,\"spriteCssClass\":\"sx_5219b1\",\"spriteMapCssClass\":\"sp_SN-oNOqlzVS\"},\"505782\":{\"sprited\":true,\"spriteCssClass\":\"sx_c0671f\",\"spriteMapCssClass\":\"sp_SN-oNOqlzVS\"},\"505794\":{\"sprited\":true,\"spriteCssClass\":\"sx_8cf344\",\"spriteMapCssClass\":\"sp_SN-oNOqlzVS\"},\"495429\":
```

Does anyone know what kind of data this is and how to convert it into data I can understand?  When I show the page source of the webpage on the browser none of this weird data shows up.  In other words the data I get from the webclient doesn't look at all like the page source on the browser.

Comment: That looks like partial JSON with backslashes escaped. If possible, can you provide the actual URL you're trying to access?

Comment: I don't think you have a problem with character encoding, its not an issue with how the characters are represented as bytes.Your problem is, you are expecting HTML and you are getting something else, looks a bit like JSON.

Comment: If it's encoded in UTF8, the ASCII range will look the same.

Comment: I do not see anything that looks like unicode.  What are you trying to change?

Comment: I am accesssing my facebook page with my user id which I don't really want to show.  it s https://www.facebook.com/my id.   Some of the data does look like web data but not all.

Comment: The site may be using the fact that your web client isn't presenting itself as a browser with the `User-Agent` as an incentive to present its data as JSON, rather than rendering it in HTML. Alternatively, the "source" you're inspecting may be a DOM tree already modified by the site executing JavaScript, which your download wouldn't run. Try something like Fiddler to see what's actually going over the wire.

Comment: What [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header are you sending with your request? If you are calling an Web API you are probably going to get JSON back by default.

Comment: It seems like I need to add the User-Agent type to my webclient.  Does anyone know what user-agent value to use?

Comment: *webpage data looks like* looks like where? Because Visual Studio will escape `"` automatically. That does not mean that the `"` is escaped in the underlying data. To be clear there is no encoding issue here. That encoding is fine, the `\"` is an escape sequence to allow you to include `"` in strings, e.g. `string test = "this \"string\" is a string";`

Comment: If you seek some data what obstacle is UTF-8 text format? Web pages usually have they format specified in header. You can check with this.

Comment: Isn't it against facebooks EULA to crawl their pages?

Comment: I am using my facebook page only for testing.  Besides what prevents Google from crawling webpages, including Facebook pages

Answer (score 0):

Is that the full web page data below? It looks incomplete on both ends.To me, it looks like JSON data to me. You can convert it into a C# object by using the JavaScriptSerializer class.

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Test resultingData = (Test)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(your_data);
```

Comment: I just showed a small segment of the data.  It is a huge data around 400K bytes.

Comment: whats your point? @Dave this will create an object of a 400Kb json no problem, BTW 400kb ain't that big

Comment: @Dave, your code above loads all the data into a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read JSON from a request, do it [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5566981/659190),

```
var json = web.DownloadString(page);
```

Then you need to deserialize the string into an object, if you know the type of the model in response, you can do it like this, lets day its `ResponseType`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseType>(json);
```

There is a NuGet package called [Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook) which you can import to your project. This will give you some models that might match up with the type.

---

If you don't know the type of the response you could do  something like this,

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Then you can [use LINQ to query the object.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: I added the user-agent "Mozilla/4.0" to my webclient Headers and now the webclient result will not let me read my Facebook webpage giving me an open error.  If I remove the user-agent from the Headers and try to read the data stream returned with a json reader, I get an error saying it found an error at position 0.  So it seems that it is impossible to correctly read a facebook webpage.  I will tried using another webpage for my testing and everything came out the way I expected.

Comment: @Dave, is that a new question? My answer assumes you can get the JSON, like in the question.